# Expire geospatial items in Redis

Tags: redis, geospatial

There are proposals for sorted set item expiration in Redis (see https://groups.google.com/d/msg/redis-db/rXXMCLNkNSs/Bcbd5Ae12qQJ and https://quickleft.com/blog/how-to-create-and-expire-list-items-in-redis/), I tried the worker approach to expire geospatial indexes with ZREMRANGEBYSCORE and ZREMRANGEBYRANK commands unsuccessfully (nothing removed).

I succeded using ZREMRANGEBYLEX.

Is there a way to work with geospatial items score other than Strings?

**Update**:

For example, if time to live(ttl) of an item is 30sec, I add it as:

```
geoadd 1 -8.616021 41.154503 30
```

Now, suppose worker executes after 40sec, I was expecting that

```
zremrangebyscore 1 0 40
```

would do the job, but it does not,

```
ZREMRANGEBYLEX 1 [0 [40
```

does it. Why is this behavior? That means the score of a geospatial item supports only lexicographical operations?

Comment: Geosets are Sorted Sets, so you can remove the elements using any `ZREM*` commands. The scores are the coordinates, encoded using geohash, so while removing by score and/or rank is possible, it doesn't make much sense. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Hi, I want to remove all expired items. In order to do that, I use the member(score) as the time to live(ttl) value. Please, see the updated question. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorted Sets have elements (strings), and every element has a score (floating-point). Geosets use the score to encode a coordinate.

Redis doesn't expire members in a Sorted Set (or a Geoset). You have to remove them yourself if that is required.

In your case, you'll need to keep two Sorted Sets - one as your GeoSet and one for managing TTLs as scores.

For example, assuming your member is called 'foo', to add it:

```
ZADD ttls 30 foo
ZADD elems -8.616021 41.154503 foo
```

To manually expire, first find the members with a call to `ZRANGEBYSCORE ttls`, and then remove them from both Sets.

Tip: it is preferable to use a timestamp as score instead of seconds.

Comment: What will be more efficient? To remove outdated items by triggering the clean process every 5 seconds for example (5 seconds is a validity time of the coordintaes), or to do the clean process in pipeline with each call to elems (I have 1000 calls per second to elems)?

Comment: I'd test it... but intuitively I'd go with the periodic cleaner despite the extra complexity of keeping it up